# What does "black voice" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, collocation

What does "black voice" mean? I've seen it in the *Peter Pan* book:

> 'Captain, let go,' he cried, writhing. Now for the first time we hear the voice of Hook. It was a black voice. 'Put back that pistol first,' it said threateningly.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: I'm not aware that it has an established meaning as an idiom. Its interpretation will depend on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context the book is discussing the "black voice" of Hook. The expression is not a common one to my knowledge. However black is a color associated with doom and gloom. So I'd assume this to me that the voice was really scary and foreboding.

Comment: Defn 5,6 or 7 here http://www.dictionary.com/browse/black

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Looking up the definition of black is a great additional point. I was making it complex by thinking idiom.

Comment: the dictionary should be the first stop for these sorts of questions - it shouldn't even really make it to being posted TBH.